# Continuously and extending a function. What about differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose that $f,g\colon \mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ are continuous, $f(0)=g(0)=0$, and that $g'(0)\neq 0$

Can we continously extend $\frac{f}{g}$ to a function which is defined at the origin?

Can we extend $\frac{f}{g}$ to a differentiable function?

*Attempt*:

Using taylor series, we can approximate this ( I am not sure how rigorous this step is)

$\frac{f}{g}\sim\frac{ f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+...}{g(a)+g'(a)(x-a)+\frac{g''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+...}$

Plugging in $x=a$,

$=\frac{ f(0)+f'(0)(x)+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}(x)^2+...}{g(0)+g'(0)(x)+\frac{g''(0)}{2!}(x)^2+...}=\frac{f'(0)(x)+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}(x)^2+...}{g'(0)(x)+\frac{g''(0)}{2!}(x)^2+...}$

Now we can divide factor out the $x$ (also seems very non-rigorous)

$\sim \frac{f'(0)+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}(x)+...}{g'(0)+\frac{g''(0)}{2!}(x)+...}$

and taking the limit as $x\to 0$ we can get that at the origin the value would be $\frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}$.

What more could be said about this sort of problem? How would one go about addressing if its differentiable at the origin?

Comment: I dont know if your approach would work (anyway it seems out of the scope to assume that $f$ is differentiable and that $g$ is twice differentiable). I would try the asymptotic $g(x)\in g'(0)x+\mathcal o(x)$ as $x\to 0$, take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_in_one_real_variable)

Comment: You assume only that $g$ is continuous, but then you also write $g'(0) \neq 0$ -- so is $g$ differentiable? Or only differentiable at $0$? Anyway, your approach seems too strong: for the Taylor series of $f, g$ you need to have that $f, g$ are differentiable, perhaps multiple times.